# magick image resize

Tags: r, image-resizing

I am using `magick` library in R.

I am using the following command but it is not working correctly

```
shoe <- image_read('F:/photo.jpg')
image_scale(shoe,'382x509')

format width height colorspace filesize
JPEG   382    460       sRGB        0
```

The width is set to 382 but not height. so I set height by following command

```
image_scale(shoe,'X509')

format width height colorspace filesize
JPEG   423    509       sRGB        0
```

Now it changed the width. Is there any way to turn off the aspect ratio while resizing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Reading the original documentation [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Geometry.html) brings the solution:

```
image_scale(shoe,"382x509!")
#  format width height colorspace filesize
#1   JPEG   382    509       sRGB        0
```